# How can I resolve a Zwick TestExport Error Exporting to Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, export

I am running a Zwick TestExpert program.

When exporting data from a file to Word, this will produce the file fine. However when exporting to Excel, I get the message as follows:

> testExpert error no. 59001: An error at Excel export occurred.

I realize this is a very bespoke piece of software, but maybe it's a general error that someone can help with?

Comment: That is a very specific piece of software, so you may not get a lot of response here. The error states it is an error from testExpert. Have you contacted Zwick?

Answer (score 0):

Error 59001 is an testXpert export error occuring at the moment you will try to export more than one sample with the same sample name. excel is not able to handle sheets with the same name. just rename your samples in testXpert uniquely to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue on one of my pcs. i was running test expert 1.61 then did an upgrade to get the export function. a new disc arrived by mail containing the new license. performed the .exe and went to export old data. just seconds into the export got the 59001 error. wiped my hdd of all zwick software and did a fresh install. problem persisted. installed on a second pc, export was successful. zwick help line was saying it could be an issue with my companies firewall which seemed odd as it is not downloading the export... my company was saying it was zwicks software but seeing as how 1.61 had been issued 6 month earlier that didnt seem right. and the fact it worked on other computers ....

my company uses office 365 so i did a quick repair of the program. add/remove program -> programs and features -> selected office 365 -> right click -> change -> repair -> quick ....

problem solved.

hope this helps.

i will contact zwick to let them know this also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).